# Execution plan templates in Wso2 CEP

Tags: apache-kafka, siddhi

I am using WSO2 CEP for processing the events coming from a Kafka topic. I want to generalise this to multiple kafka topics which stores logs in similar format i.e each partition of each topic stores data of a particular person.

The scenario is as follows; a topic indicates a super group where each partition is a person in that group. In each partition, exists JSON formatted data points {bank transaction information (time of transaction, credit/debit, amount) etc} of that person.

I want to be able to break the data in such a way that finally I get streams of amount credited/debited by the person, i.e after first(level of) execution plan different person data is broken into individual data streams followed by second(level of) execution plan which further breaks each stream into (timestamp, credit/debit) stream and (timestamp, amount) stream.

Naive way to achieve this is to write a program which writes out execution plans(siddhisql file), event streams(JSON files), event receivers and publishers(XML files) for you programmatically. But, as the number of topics increases the number of these files increases.

Is there any template way of doing this(atleast creating execution plans)?

Answer (score 0):

You can create Execution Templates where you can define an execution plan template and could include the required streams for the template. When you define the template you can define parameters which can be configured with actual values later. In the current released CEP does not support to include receivers and publishers for the template.

Please refer the WSO2 documentation n [Creating Execution Templates](https://docs.wso2.com/display/CEP400/Creating+Execution+Templates). To get more idea on the template structure please refer [this blog post](http://blog.tharik.org/2015/09/user-friendly-execution-management-with.html).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But it is not what I am expecting.

Is it possible to use placeholder variable for choosing receiving and publishing streams? i.e. I get a drop down with available streams and I choose the one I am interested in?

Comment: Technically its possible but drop down content would be complex. In Siddhi query template you can place a parameter with $ where you define the stream. Option definitions could be included for drop down list values. These values contains the stream and its parameters.